# How to convert an Object {} to an Array [] of objects with different structure?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have this object in javascript:

```
let obj= 
{
  a: {
       a1: [5,5],
       a2: [6,6]
     },
  b: {
       a1: [7,7],
       a2: [8,8]
     },
  c: {
       a1: [9,9],
       a2: [3,3]
     }
}
```

And I want to convert it to an array like this:

```
let arr = 
[
  {
    name: 'a1',
    a: [5,5],
    b: [7,7],
    c: [9,9]
  },
  {
    name: 'a2',
    a: [6,6],
    b: [8,8],
    c: [3,3]
  }
]
```

I tried to make the array this way:

```
Object.entries(obj).map(([key, value]) => ({key,value}));
```

But I don't know how to change the structure.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `reduce` with `Object.entries` to create an object and then use `Object.values`.

```js
let object = {"a":{"a1":[5,5],"a2":[6,6]},"b":{"a1":[7,7],"a2":[8,8]},"c":{"a1":[9,9],"a2":[3,3]}}

const result = Object.entries(object).reduce((r, [k, v]) => {
  return Object.entries(v).forEach(([kn, vn]) => {
    if (!r[kn]) r[kn] = {name: kn,[k]: vn}
    else r[kn][k] = vn
  }), r
}, {})

console.log(Object.values(result))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also achieve the same with `Object.keys` & `Array.reduce`:

```js
let obj = { a: { a1: [5, 5], a2: [6, 6] }, b: { a1: [7, 7], a2: [8, 8] }, c: { a1: [9, 9], a2: [3, 3] } }

const result = Object.keys(obj).reduce((r,k) => (Object.keys(obj[k]).forEach(a => {
  r[a] = r[a] || { name: a }
  r[a][k] = obj[k][a]
}), r), {})

console.log(Object.values(result))
```